# Javascript based drawing library for free hand drawing?

Tags: javascript, drawing

I've seen there's a lot of libraries that will allow me to output shapes and lines but do these libraries allow for freehand drawing using the mouse?

I want to allow users to draw and then to save their work to database.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using canvas. There was a question similar to this a few months ago [Javascript drawing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96486/javascript-drawing-library). There is [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) that allows you to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do this .. wouldn't be all that tricky .. take a look at the [Raphael Javascript drawing library](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for that too and asked the same question a few days ago. Maybe I'm overlooking something but none of all these drawing libraries actually allows freehand drawing (i.e. the capturing of movements of a mouse or pen made by a human). The only two answers I found were here:
[Online Photoshop via HTML 5's Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825958/online-photoshop-via-html-5s-canvas)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.kolchose.org/simon/ajaximagemapcreator/ (Click onto the image area twice!)

http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm

Comment: Typical result of just posting links.... They are both not available and thus the answer is useless.